# How to implement an authentication within Blazor Server App with JWT from Web API

Tags: authentication, jwt, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app which wants to connect to a .Net Core WebApi. The app should send an authentication request and the WebApi returns a JWT containing user data. For any further communication with the WebApi the JWT should be used to authorize against it.
I'd like to ensure that only authenticated users can access the server app. If someone is not authenticated he or she should be redirected to a login page.
Up to now I've used a combination of default Identity with AzureAD authentication.
Is there any option to have a JWT authentication working the same way?